# Identifying the hidden lyrics in the song "Born to be Wasted"

Tags: lyrics, meaning

One of the most "nostalgic" songs in the late 2000s, which circulated around YouTube so that it came to be considered by many to be its national anthem, is the song "Born to be Wasted" by 009 Sound System. This song, written by Alexander Perls in 2009, talks about drug abuse, war, and how life is short. The link to the song is here

I have noticed that between 1:55-2:27 there are some vocal chop effects with reversed audio. I am curious to know what was said there. I have used an online audio reverser to completely reverse the song so that between the mentioned time interval I could hear clearly what was said (since by reversing a reversed audio, the reversed part becomes sequential). I managed to decode one statement which corresponds to minute 2:15 where he says "there's a God for me". I hope someone can help me identify the other hidden lyrics.

Answer (score 1):

I did reverse the part even isolated the vocals as well and to me it sounds like "If all or anything you will not make yourself an idol" the second subliminal message is the "there is a God for me" and the last one sounded like "without a tear" that's what I heard. Fun fact i know the first two are correct because i used them for my cover of New Divide but If you want here is the video I made with the vocals isolated